# How is the requirement for badges decided?

Tags: discussion, badges

We can see that some of the badges like **Great Answer, Populist, Reversal, Unsung Hero** have never been awarded. The Requirements for **Great Answer** is good, for others it is a bit fictious. Like for **Reversal**, if questions get negative votes then most probably the user will remove it or the community will. there is low chance that anyone has good answer. and seemingly less is the chance of answer scoring 20.

For **Populist**, the accepted answer has to have score of 10, which means it is a nice answer and useful to others as well. Then the other answer has to get 2x that means atleast 20 score. I see very low possibility that such an answer can come and even it it comes it should be the accepted answer. There is a possibility is one person gives a nice answer and anether gives gives good answer ( explaining concepts, otherwise it won't get 20) but it looks like practicably unreachable.

It says *Gold badges recognize important contributions from members of the community. They are rarely awarded.* but the limits should be reachable.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=gold for evidence that every badge can be attained.

Comment: Note though that the GIS.se user base is a tiny fraction of StackOverflow's, so many badges based on viewership and votes will take much longer to achieve here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These are system-wide requirements developed for SO and applied without modification to all other StackExchange sites.

All badges will become possible (indeed, plentiful) when one or both of two things happen:

1. The active community grows.
2. People vote more generously on answers and questions.

Please: vote early and often, every day.